# Urgent: sponsorship and Invitation for Portugal Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, portugal

We are a group of 3 Indian students who have been invited to Porto, Portugal for a competition. The inviting university (University of Porto) is paying for our hotel, food and local travel costs. We are also extending our trip and visiting Paris for 2 days. We have already submitted our visa application to the embassy.

For the proof of financial stability, we submitted copies of our parents’ bank statements and PAN card details along with a scan of signed sponsorship letter from them. However, since we are away from home, we did not have original affidavits from our parents. At the VFS centre, we were told that an original affidavit is required. We submitted our applications anyway (without affidavit). The VFS employee wrote on our checklist that there is no original affidavit.
We would like to know how this affects our chances of getting the visa?

Moreover, we have an Invitation letter from the University of Porto. That letter is digitally signed. Which means that it must be handled electronically. At VFS, we were not able to submit an e-copy of the letter. So we submitted a printed copy instead. However, we were told by the University of Porto that we must send the invitation letters to the embassy by e-mail. How exactly are we supposed to send the invitation letters? To which e-mail address? And how do we imply that we have already applied via VFS and these invitation letters correspond to our applications?
We found a contacts link [here](https://www.novadeli.embaixadaportugal.mne.pt/en/the-embassy/contacts):

Is that the correct e-mail id to send the letters?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can I ask you to split this into two questions - one about affidavits and one about emailing the embassy?